# How to indent multi-line in vim/gvim?

Tags: vim, shortcut

I want to indent multi-line in 'vim/gvim', is there any shortcut in the vim/gvim?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The indent commands `=`, `<` and `>` can be combined with [all movement commands and text objects](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html). For example:

```
>G     Indent until end of file
>}     Indent until next paragraph
>iB    Indent contents of current { } block
```

They also indent text selected in visual mode.

Use <kbd><</kbd> to un-indent or <kbd>=</kbd> to re-indent ('format' using the filetype settings).

Comment: `=` is the 'indent' command, but honestly I think in user-speak to 'indent' usually means `>` (to _increase_ the indent level), so I'll take the liberty to change the samples to use it

Comment: +1 for suggesting the `=` option. While usually using `>` or `<` is what is desired, it's extremely useful to know that the `=` re-indent is available.

Comment: apart from just pressing `==` to smart indent, using `=` with a movement to a block that you want to align to (e.g. `=j` or `=k`) gives a satisfying level of control.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Try:

```
V             # To switch to visual mode. Select lines, and...
>             # Indent (use `<` to de-indent, or with a number just before to indent several times).
```